# Perl win32::GUI text more than the window

Tags: perl

My script will print output in label. My window size is 100 lines length. Please let me know how to show more than the window data in lable. Ex: 200 lines output.

I have problem with textfield output. so using only label. Is there any way of scroll the text in lable??

Thanks
Sri

Answer (score 0):

What is label? You are likely to get a better response if you tag the question with what the question is concerned with.

This may or not be of any help; the special variable `$=` holds output page-size by line. You might be able to localise for the print. (If it is still in use).

```
my $perlvar = 'hello'."\n" x 150;
{
 local $= = 200; # set page-size to 200 on default output filehandle
 print $perlvar;
} 
 # $= returns to default page-size on default output filehandle
```

perlvar is also the name of the perldoc which tells about perl variables